# Unpublish a vhdx application from Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, msix

---

**Problem Statement:**
So I am trying to write a dotnet project to app attach a vhdx application in AVD. There is also a need to un-publish or remove the same application from the AVD instance. I understand that I need to remove it from the host pool and application group; after this, I need to remove the vhdx from the appropriate file share container.

I see that these PowerShell commands are allowing me to that:

```
$applicationGroup = "AG"
$resoureGroupName = "RG"
$hostPoolName = "HG"
$applicationName = "AN"


Get-AzWvdApplication -ApplicationGroupName $applicationGroup -ResourceGroupName $resoureGroupName

Remove-AzWvdMsixPackage -FullName $applicationName -HostPoolName $hostPoolName -ResourceGroupName $resoureGroupName

Get-AzWvdApplication -ApplicationGroupName $applicationGroup -ResourceGroupName $resoureGroupName

Remove-AzWvdApplication -ApplicationGroupName $applicationGroup -Name $applicationName -ResourceGroupName $resoureGroupName
```

The above commands work, but I get an error while deleting the vhdx file from the file share. I switched off all my VMs and tried deleting the file, which then got deleted.

I am leveraging Azure.Storage.Files Nuget to deal with the file share operations (I have the appropriate connection string to do this).

I am facing an error while deleting the file share - since the VM where the file share is linked is running and has a virtual lock on the vhdx mentioned above.

---

**Ask:**

How do I achieve this without shutting down the VM since I wouldn't be aware which VM had the application installed?

Or is there any other way to achieve all of this (detaching the vhdx altogether) easily?

---

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the VHDX file is open by the VM(s) attaching to the app. You can validate this by running the following PS script (you need the Access Key of the Storage Account though):

```
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"

Get-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $Context -ShareName "<FileShareName>" -Recursive | Select Path, ClientIp
```

[image]

(Just for validation, `ClientIp` should match the IP of the VM(s) having a connection to the file).

[image]

By closing the handle, you will then be able to delete the file by running this  cmdlet (using `Path` from the previous result, although you should already know the path anyway):

```
Close-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $Context -ShareName "<FileShareName>" -Path "<Path>" -CloseAll
```